# PHP SQL SELECT from WHERE isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I know that this is very thoroughly covered on stack overflow, but I cannot figure it out. I am completely new to PHP and SQL commands so please bear with me.

Here is my code:

```
    $connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
    $dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());

    $studentid = $_POST['student_id'];

    $result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    echo $row['first_name']
```

I am sure that it is probably something really stupid. I know that i should be using mysqli or something but this is just a test project to teach me some basics.

student_id is from the previous php page, and I want it to lookup student_id and display the first name of the student where I put echo from the table named students, but I get nothing on the page and there is no entry in the error log.

student_id is both the name of the column and the name of the input field on the previous php page.

Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, but the code from $connection to the while statement are in one

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: add some basic debugging

Comment: You're mixing your MySQL APIs, they do "not" mix.

Comment: Yeah basically you can't use mysql and mysqli functions interchangeably like this.

Comment: Don't put this live, there's a SQL injection vuln here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing your MySQL APIs, they do "not" mix.

Change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_array` if you really want to use `mysql_*`

Plus, put some bracing in:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // missing brace
echo $row['first_name'] // <= missing semi-colon
```

and a semi-colon at the end of `echo $row['first_name']`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['first_name'];
}
```

Also, your DB connection here, goes at the end, not at the beginning: Unlike the `mysqli_*` method, it goes first. Using `mysql_`, the connection goes at the end. If you really want to use `mysqli_*` functions, then you'll need to change all `mysql_` to `mysqli_` (which follows).

```
$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'");
```

which isn't really needed, since a DB connection has been established. (I've placed it at the end though).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'",$connection);
```

Plus, use `$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['student_id']), $connection);` for added protection, if you're still keen on using `mysql_*` based functions.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

MySQL (error reporting links)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

---

## However...

---

Here's a full `mysqli_` based method: adding [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) to the POST variable.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbname) 
or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysqli_error());

$studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['student_id']);

$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['first_name'];
}
```

And technically speaking...

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

---

### Regarding SQL injection:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

Comment: Thank You!! I figured it out from your info. So helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. When you can, just tick that white outlined checkmark till it turns Green, so we can close the question. This informs everyone on SO that a solution has been found. @dster77 Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change all the `mysql` to `mysqli`;

Also add a semicolon after your `echo` and curly braces { and } for your `while`

Answer (score 0):

Add curly braces around the statement that is supposed to be executed in the while loop.
I'd also suggest you check out mysql_real_escape_string, to avoid SQL Injection ;-)
Also you have to remove the i in mysqli, since youre using the old MySQL functions.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
$dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());

$studentid = $_POST['student_id'];

$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['first_name']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a lot of little problems here.

First **mysql_query()** 's syntax is:

```
mysql_query(query,connection)
```

so the connection should be the second argument.

In the query string you have to put `` around the column you are comparing to, like this:

```
WHERE `student_id` = '$studentid'
      ^here      ^and here
```

**mysql_query()** and **mysqli_fetch_array()** can't work together.

It's either **mysql_query()** with **mysql_fetch_array()** 
 or **mysqli_query()** with **mysqli_fetch_array()**.

You have a missing semi-colon on this row:

```
echo $row['first_name'] // <- here
```

Also check if the value from **$_POST['student_id']** is the one you expect.

That's what I see for now.

Answer (score 0):

I find using mysqli is much faster to connect and call out your results

```
$connection = new mysqli($serverName, $userName, $password, $databaseName)

if ($connection->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}


$studentid = $_POST['student_id'];

$sql = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'";

$results = $connection->query($sql);
```

If you're just checking for one student, I would just grab one row

```
if($results->num_rows == 1){
    $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['first_name'];
}
```

If you're trying to grab multi student ids

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['first_name'];
}
```